# How to do Unit test for Asp.net which of type website?

Tags: asp.net

I created asp.net website not a project. Now I would like to do unit testing for that website. I created unit test project but problem arises when I tried to reference that website i.e., that website reference is not coming while adding reference.

Comment: You have to precompile the site. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly unit test asp.net website project due the website project only compiles at runtime and unit test require reference to classes that are part of compiled DLL. The options you have available are:

1. Convert your website into a web application project and unit test as accordingly.
2. Or move the relevent code from `App_Code` to a library project and then reference the DLL to your website project.

Both of the above options will provide access to the classes in a compiled dll format which can can be used to unit test.

I hope this helps